# Why was this question closed as duplicate when it isn't identical?

Tags: discussion

- [My question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670325/how-to-split-into-sublists-using-linq) (closed as duplicate)
- [Other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419019/split-list-into-sublists-with-linq)

These programming questions are looking for a way to split a list into sublists but want different output orderings. The accepted answers may seem the same but differ by one character that makes the solutions produce the differently ordered results.

The difference may be subtle but I don't think they can be called duplicates.

Comment: 5 people voted for it to be closed as such, so the subtlety was lost on them. I have no idea if they were right or not, btw.

Comment: *differ by one character that makes the solutions produce the differently ordered results* — but did you need a separate question to figure that detail out? If so, why didn't you refer to that other question in your question, explaining why it didn't work for you? And give it a more explicit title than the duplicate?

Comment: I have clarified the title and detail, and added a reference ot my similar question in the other question.

Comment: Changing the auto-inserted duplicate comment is very much frowned upon; please revert that. (And note that questions that refer to one another are automatically shown in the "Linked" section on the right; that's one of the beauties of closing as a duplicate too.)

Answer (score 3):

Both questions (and answers) cover the same ground. The difference corresponds to a matrix transposition/exchanging row and column index in a matrix.

I believe that difference was deemed too minor to consider the questions different, since the principle is so commonplace and widely known.

If the "Exact duplicate" reason were interpreted so narrowly that this sort of minute differences precludes closure as a duplicate, hardly any question could ever be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

Both questions seem very similar and that is probably why they were flagged and marked as duplicates.

In the future, if you find another question that is similar to the one you are asking but it doesn't answer your question, then I would suggest to at least reference it in your post.

Just by including the following in your question would be helpful to other users when they read your question:

*I am stuck with a problem that is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419019/split-list-into-sublists-with-linq) but it is different because they are looking for a way to split a list into sublists but want different output orderings*

This type of effort shows that you at least researched the problem and could not find an adequate solution.